# How to track down why a post model results in nil :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running into an error with `new_post_path` (I am creating posts with text and images basically in a list for users to select), `Post.new` creates @post, however `@post.id` and `params[:id]` are nil, why is `:id` nil even after Post.new, shouldn't the `params[:id]` be created upon `Post.new`?  If not how do I pass in `params[:id]` to the `posts_path(action: :create)`?  I am guessing I am just confused about at which point a new @post instance is created.

I have tried different syntax and I am actually running into errors about syntax now after changing my code around, for instance omitting "url:" in `_form.html.erb` in `form_with()` it only complains about an unexpected ",". I am afraid I might just have my syntax out of order.

Here is the relevant code:

app/views/posts/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "New post", new_post_path(category_name: params[:category_name], section_name: params[:section_name], section_id: params[:section_id])%>
```

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
def new
@post = Post.new
@post.id = params[:id]
@post.verification_id = SecureRandom.hex(4)
@post.section_id = params[:section_id]
@post.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
end
```

error message

```
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil, :section_id=>1,   :uuid=>"8e5f67bf-bba4-488f-8d8f-08db8630a210"}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]
Did you mean?  uuid_posts_url
```

app/views/posts/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: @post, url: uuid_posts_path(id: @post.id, section_id: @post.section_id, uuid: @post.uuid), action: :create) do |form| %>
```

I have been experimenting and learning Ruby on Rails for a few years, and I am confused still about if Post.new generates a @post.id or `params[:id]`, according to the error, no it does not.  If not, how do I generate an id since it is required I believe for the _form.html.erb to create a @post instance?

Comment: the new method in your controller creates an unsaved Post instance for your form to work with. `Post.new` is this unsaved Post instance. b/c it's unsaved, it doesn't have an id.

Comment: Thank you for clearning that up I just wanted to know more about :id and did in fact clear it up removing :id from the routes so that turned out to be the problem not Post.new or Post.create making an :id, thanks for your help

Comment: :id is created when the post record has been successfully saved to the database.